# Authentication Failed Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I'm doing an assignment that we were supposed to get from Github. I completed it and now we have to commit the changes on our own branch, publish, and then submit a pull request. I was able to commit the changes but when I hit "publish", I get this error message:

[image: Screenshot]

These were all step-by-step, illustrated instructions from my professor on Github Desktop so I have no idea what I may be doing wrong. I haven't found any information on this error message on Github and I did find one post on here but it was far too technical for me to understand and it didn't seem the issue was resolved anyhow.

Comment: I should add I did restart the app, logged out/back in, and changed my password to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I met a similar problem. The solution that I found is to sign out and re-sign in your github account. You can do it under File\Options\Accounts.